# Ubuntu 16.04 + NVIDIA GF114 GeForce GTX 560 Ti + Nvidia Driver = errors

Tags: nvidia, 16.04

When I start Ubuntu I get this

[image]

If I install driver 340 then I have a black screen

I use the latest driver

[image: 361 driver selected in Additional Drivers]

```
    $ lspci -v | grep -A 14 NVIDIA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF114 [GeForce GTX 560 Ti] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Memory at f8000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Memory at c8000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    Memory at d4000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64M]
    I/O ports at cf00 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at fa000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_361

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF114 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Memory at fbffc000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

02:00.0 SATA controller: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB363 SATA/IDE Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB363 SATA/IDE Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at fdffe000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at fdf00000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
```

`xorg.conf`:

```
    # nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 361.42  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-13)  Tue Mar 22 18:37:28 PDT 2016

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had an issue when I installed 16.04 where my laptop would boot to low graphics mode or just a black screen. It's a slightly different problem, but the same solution should apply.

1. Make sure all NVIDIA drivers are uninstalled by running `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`.
2. Run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` and then `sudo apt-get update`.
3. Run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-364` to install the newest NVIDIA driver from this repository.

It seems you know your way around the terminal and/or TTY, so hopefully those steps are detailed enough. If not, leave a comment, and I'll add more in.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `nvidia-graphics-drivers-364` instead of `nvidia-364`? That's the package name listed on [the PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=xenial).

Comment: @Joschua nvidia-364 might be a meta package that points to everything that needs to be installed. All I know is that it works, and it's what is recommended to be installed.